# what does ' '!K13 mean ? (empty cell reference)

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I have copied a excel sheet from here
http://www.dfb.de/vereinsmitarbeiter/jugendleiterin/artikel/turnierplaene-als-download-85/ ('Turnierplan 1d')

and I wonder what this means: (blank reference)

' '!K13

' '!A12

Its inside a when:

```
=WENN(' '!K13=0;"Final";WENN(' '!A12<>' '!K12;"same values are missing";"Final"))
```

Where do set or see the referenced cells?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part before the exclamation mark within a cell reference is the worksheet name. So `' '!K13` is a reference to `K13` on a hidden sheet named only a empty space " ".

The hidden sheet is hidden with `xlSheetVeryHidden`. So it can't be unhided the default way.

Open the VBA-Editor, select the `Tabelle3 ( )` and unhide it using the properties table.
[image]

Comment: Might also be a non-breaking space (e.g. Chr(160)) or some unicode space character.

Comment: Thank you Axel Richter, perfect answer for me!
(For excel newbies: start VBA-Editor with ALT + F11)